# In a R, how to choose the elements of a list of lists according to the value of an element of the sublists?

Tags: r, list

Let's say that in R we have the following list of lists, called `A`:

```
A <- list();
for (i in c(1:1000)) {
    A[[i]] <- list(sample(LETTERS, 1, T), runif(1, 1, 1000))
}
```

Such that for each element `i` of `A`, `A[[i]][[1]]` will be a randomly assigned letter and `A[[i]][[2]]` will be a randomly assigned number from 1 to 1000.

That being the case, is there a way, preferably without a loop, to dentify which elements `j` of `A` contain a list with second element greater than, say, 500? I.e. such that `A[[j]][[2]] > 500`?

If we were working with data-frames, we could use the function `which`. But I don't see how to achieve that with a list of lists.

Comment: If you're making indices to subset the list, you can filter directly: `Filter(function(x){x[[2]] > 500}, A)`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sapply` to return a logical `vector`

```
i1 <- sapply(A, function(x)  x[[2]]>500)
```

Or without anonymous function call

```
i2 <- sapply(A, `[[`, 2)> 500

identical(i1, i2)
#[1] TRUE
```

This index can be used to filter the 'A'

```
A[i1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too (to generate the logical vector):

```
unlist(A, recursive = FALSE)[seq(2,2*length(A),2)] > 500
```